# How to get point information to update when dragging in Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on a program to allow people to draw arrows on a page with their mouse. They can select/deselect arrows and modify their location and size. Pressing delete will remove the arrow.  I have it mostly working, but I can't get it when a user drags the arrow to have the sizing handles follow it.  Also, when they click on a sizing handle, the arrow on the end next to the dot changes size.  Can't figure out what coordinates I'm supposed to be using.  The other end is fine.  Here is the code on my site:  http://www.mtncom.net/doug/

Comment: Stack overflow encourages authors of questions to provide relevant code snippets in the question instead of pointing to an external site to get the code. There are many reasons for this, but two important ones are: it makes it easier for readers and potential answer authors to understand your case and provide answers, and it preserves the code in case code is ever moved or removed from the external URL.

Comment: Makes sense. I was able to get it figured out after a bit of trial and error.